# Problems with upgrading MySQL

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, mysql

In a bit of a mess here. I tried without success to upgrade my MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7. I am running a Mint 17.2 spin. The apt-get failed due to a network error and none of the usual apt "fix" routines work. I have been trying to get rid of everything manually using `dpkg` and I thought I did it.

Running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.17-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then having a looksee

```
apt-mark showhold
```

I get nothing.

Thinking `aptitude` might sort it out:

```
addinall@Fermi /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ sudo aptitude install mysql-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client{a} mysql-community-client{ab} mysql-community-server{ab} mysql-server 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 32.1 MB of archives. After unpacking 237 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: libmecab2 (>= 0.996-1.2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed.
                          Depends:    Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Selecting `n`:

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                                    
1)     libdbd-mysql-perl [4.025-1ubuntu0.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]           
2)     libdbi-perl [1.630-1 (trusty)]                                                   
3)     libmysqlclient18 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (now, trusty-security, trusty-updates)]
4)     mysql-client [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]         
5)     mysql-client-5.5 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]     
6)     mysql-client-core-5.5 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                              
7)     mysql-community-client [Not Installed]                                           
8)     mysql-community-server [Not Installed]                                           
9)     mysql-server [Not Installed]                                                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]  libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed.
                          Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14ubuntu1 is installed.
 mysql-community-client : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed.
                          Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mysql-client [Not Installed]                       
2)     mysql-community-client [Not Installed]             
3)     mysql-community-server [Not Installed]             
4)     mysql-server [Not Installed]                       



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Selecting `y` gives:

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Selecting n

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                                    
1)     libdbd-mysql-perl [4.025-1ubuntu0.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]           
2)     libdbi-perl [1.630-1 (trusty)]                                                   
3)     libmysqlclient18 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (now, trusty-security, trusty-updates)]
4)     mysql-client [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]         
5)     mysql-client-5.5 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]     
6)     mysql-client-core-5.5 [5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (trusty-security, trusty-updates)]

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                              
7)     mysql-community-client [Not Installed]                                           
8)     mysql-community-server [Not Installed]                                           
9)     mysql-server [Not Installed]                                                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

It wants to install 5.5 again.

The contents of `mysql.list`:

```
THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look here , just in case: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84368

Comment: Have you try to manually install each dependency ? For example `apt-get install libmecab2` . then `apt-get install mysql-community-server` , etc?

Comment: First off, is your system up-to-date? Have you run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: Thanks you both for responding.  Yes the apt had been through update and upgrade.  It is a dev box so gets looked after pretty well (not well enough it seem!).  I tried to resolve the dependencies by hand but apt just got into "Dependency Hell".  After 12 hours I pulled the pin.  Copied home and var over to NAS and installed Mint 18 from clean.  In the last 20 years of Linux, the only real issue I have ever had has been with package managers.  I gave up Red Hat because of yum.


Thanks for the bug report link!  That looks a LOT like mine!

Cheers,
Mark.